# Error in Bettercap when performing MitM

Tags: man-in-the-middle, bettercap

When I start MitM attack using bettercap, my target loses connectivity. When I search something in my target device, it shows that it is connected to Wi-Fi but has no internet access.

Comment: There are many, many articles to help troubleshoot this kind of problem. And when asking for troubleshooting help, you need to provide quite a lot of details. You have provided none. And it is always helpful if you used proper sentence structure when posting.